# Excel VBA - SUM cells in column before blank cell

Tags: vba, excel, sum

I have [Excel Offer Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCOKY.jpg) with positions and macro which transfer rows from this sheet to second sheet when value in B column is different than 0. It also add empty row after word "SUMA".

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim MyOutputWorksheet As Worksheet

Sub PullData()
Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set MyWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Roboczy")
Set MyOutputWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Oferta")

    Dim myValue As Long
    Dim RowPointer As Long

    For RowPointer = 1 To MyWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If MyWorksheet.Range("B" & RowPointer).Value > 0 And MyWorksheet.Range("B" & RowPointer).Value <> "" Then
            If MyOutputWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row > 155 Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            MyWorksheet.Range(("A" & RowPointer) & ":D" & RowPointer).Copy Destination:=MyOutputWorksheet.Range("A" & MyOutputWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next RowPointer


     Dim b As Range
For Each b In MyOutputWorksheet.Range("A1:A200")
 If b.Value Like "*SUMA*" Then
 b.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
 End If
Next b

End Sub
```

I miss some code which would clear #ADR! and sum up all cells in each section. 
More details -> [Image of Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTsX3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure guess, as I can't see the Roboczy sheet, but I think you're getting what I would call a #REF! error. Likely caused by the source sheet containing a formula referencing a range that is not valid when translated to the destination sheet. Simplest solution I can think of is to Paste/Special Values instead of a general Paste to remove the formulae:
Replace your one paste line with:

```
MyWorksheet.Range(("A" & RowPointer) & ":D" & RowPointer).Copy
MyOutputWorksheet.Range("A" & Cells(MyOutputWorksheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```